# Finding all values that share a key with a given value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, one {actor:films} and the other {film:actors}, and I'm trying to create a program that will tell me all of the coactors of an inputted actor.

For example:

`dictionary1` looks like this:

```
{'Daniel Radcliffe':['Harry Potter'], 'Emma Thompson':['Harry Potter','Sense and Sensibility'], 'Alan Rickman':['Harry Potter', 'Sense and Sensibility']}
```

`dictionary2` looks like this:

```
{'Harry Potter': ['Daniel Radcliffe', 'Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman'], 'Sense and Sensibility': ['Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman', 'Hugh Grant']}
```

and if I input Alan Rickman, the output should be:

```
['Daniel Radcliffe','Emma Thompson','Hugh Grant']
```

This is the code I currently have:

```
def coactors(actor):
    dictionary1 = makeDictionaryFromFile()
    dictionary2 = makeReverseDictionary()
    films=dictionary1[actor]
    for n in films:
        if n in dictionary2.keys():
           return list(set(dictionary2[n]))
        else:
            return "There was an error, try again"
```

and the output is:

```
['Daniel Radcliffe']
```

it seems to only read the first film in the list, and not iterate through the rest of them. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
def coactors(actor):
    co_actors = []
    dictionary1 = makeDictionaryFromFile()
    dictionary2 = makeReverseDictionary()
    films=dictionary1[actor]
    for n in films:
        if n in dictionary2.keys():
            co_actors +=dictionary2[n]
    if len(co_actors) == 0:
        return "error"
    else:
        co_actors.remove(actor)
        return list(set(co_actors))
```

Comment: Thank you so much once again!

Comment: any time,there are many methods to do it, but i prefer to modify your code.

Comment: I find it so much more helpful when people do what you did, and modify my code, instead of introducing lots of new ways to do it. I can follow it much better, and it helps point out errors in my thought process.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over all films and append the results instead of returning immediately.
With your current code, only the coactors in the first film in films will be returned.

```
def coactors(actor):
dictionary1 = makeDictionaryFromFile()
dictionary2 = makeReverseDictionary()
films=dictionary1[actor]
coacts = []
for n in films:
    if n in dictionary2.keys():
        coacts += list(set(dictionary2[n]))
    else:
        return "There was an error, try again"
return coacts.remove(actor)
```

Comment: I get `None` returned

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `for n in films:` loop with this:

```
results = set(flat for flat in dictionary2.get(film, []) for film in films)
results.remove(actor)
return results
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to go through `d2.values()` it gives you a list of values of all the keys stored in one list. In your case, you will get a list of a list. You can go through the items(that are originally values of keys), whenever you find that actor in the list, You store this list, if you don't find the actor, you don't need to add this list. You will get by the end a list of a list. You can use `Reduce`, it helps you turn list of lists to a list, and `set` helps you delete duplicates, then delete the name of the actor from this list to get the names of co-actors.

The code would look like:

```
d1={'Daniel Radcliffe':['Harry Potter'], 'Emma Thompson':['Harry Potter','Sense and Sensibility'], 'Alan Rickman':['Harry Potter', 'Sense and Sensibility']}
d2={'Harry Potter': ['Daniel Radcliffe', 'Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman'], 'Sense and Sensibility': ['Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman', 'Hugh Grant']}

def coactors(actor):
    d=[list(set(x)) for x in d2.values() if actor in x]
    return list(set(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,d))-{actor}) 

print coactors('Alan Rickman') #Output: ['Hugh Grant', 'Daniel Radcliffe', 'Emma Thompson']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 l1 = {'Daniel Radcliffe':['Harry Potter'], 'Emma Thompson':['Harry Potter','Sense and Sensibility'], 'Alan Rickman':['Harry Potter', 'Sense and Sensibility']}
 l2 = {'Harry Potter': ['Daniel Radcliffe', 'Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman'], 'Sense and Sensibility': ['Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman', 'Hugh Grant']}

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     name = 'Alan Rickman'
     films = l1.get(name, None)
     if films:
         for film, names in l2.items():
             if film in films:
                 print names
```

The output is:

```
['Daniel Radcliffe', 'Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman']
['Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman', 'Hugh Grant']
```